# getElementByID keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, electron

Im currently getting the error shown in the title and I've tried to fix the problem with numerous solutions found on stackoverflow but none have worked as of yet, any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Donor Request </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label> Blood Type </label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="bloodType" value="">
        <label> Location </label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="Location" value="">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="button"> Request </button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

      const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron').remote;

      const form = document.querySelector('form')

      form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

      window.onload = function(){
        const bloodType = document.getElementById("bloodType").value;
      }

      function submitForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("working");
        console.log(bloodType, "working");
        ipcRenderer.send('Request:bloodType', bloodType);
    }

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: but there is no any `getElementByID` codes here.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha i see i accidentally copied the older version, ive updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `bloodType` as a `var` or `let` outside of onLoad to make it accessible inside another method, or obtain it from inside `submitForm`.

```
function submitForm(e){
    const bloodType = document.getElementById("bloodType").value;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("working");
    console.log(bloodType, "working");
    ipcRenderer.send('Request:bloodType', bloodType);
}
```

```
let bloodType;

window.onload = function(){
    bloodType = document.getElementById("bloodType").value;
}

function submitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("working");
    console.log(bloodType, "working");
    ipcRenderer.send('Request:bloodType', bloodType);
}
```

Comment: It does not return an ***array***.

Comment: I change answer to state `arrayLike`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `const` your variable will be confined to the scope of the function it was declared within. This means that you cannot access `bloodType` outside your `window.onload` callback function.

Instead, one possible solution could be to make `bloodType` a global variable, and then set its value within your `onload` callback like so:

```
let bloodType;
window.onload = function(){
  bloodType = document.getElementById("bloodType").value;
}
```

This way, you can access `bloodType` through all your functions, with only having to query the DOM once.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you need to define `bloodType` outside of the `window.onload` function using `let` or inside the `submitForm` function.

```
function submitForm(e) {
  let bloodType = document.getElementById("bloodType").value;

  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("working");

  console.log(bloodType, "working");
  ipcRenderer.send('Request:bloodType', bloodType);
}
```

The interesting thing here is that `bloodType` variable you use in your `submitForm` will not throw a reference error. Because `bloodType` refers to the actual input element with the `id=bloodType`.

If you have an element

```
<div id="example">some text</div>
```

`example.innerHTML` returns `some text` **without** having to create `let example = document.getElementById("example")` variable manually

So, if you were to do `bloodType.value` with your existing code, it will work. But, you should use `document.getElementById("bloodType").value`

More info: [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278)